# Manual setup of WebAPI project not retrieving data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I just created a VS 2013 WebApi 2.0 project.  I added a DataContext and defined a DbSet and Model.  I added a controller to test it all out but I am not getting any data.  I have done this many times but I can't figure out what I am not doing.

My DataContext

```
public class DriverAlertContext : DbContext
{
    public DriverAlertContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Drivers> Drivers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicles> Vehicles { get; set; }

}
```

My Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Companies> Get()
{
   var x = db.Companies;

   return x;
}
```

I get an empty set [] as a reply.  When I browse the datatable I see data.  My connection string is correct.  What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be lazy evaluation. Entity framework doesn't actually pull anything from the database into your dbsets until you ask for it by iterating through the set or calling the load method on the dbset (or a number of other possible things).

Calling ToList is an easy way to force Entity Framework to execute a query and pull the data from your database into memory.

Try

```
db.Companies.Select(x=>x).ToList();
```

Comment: That is not it.  I tried your suggestion and there are 0 records found.  Besides I have done that method before in other projects with success.